# VS2015 Will not statically link runtime library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static

I'm working on a project for a client and he can't run it because he doesn't have the visual studio DLL's installed and doesn't want to install them which I totally understand.

I'm trying to compile my project so he can run it without the DLL's and having no luck.

My project settings are: 
C++-> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions:

```
WIN32
_DEBUG
_WINDOWS
_STATIC_CPPLIB
```

C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime library:

```
 Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)
```

Configuration: Active (Debug)    Platform: Active(Win32)

But when I clean/rebuild and run the executable on my virtual machine without the libraries I get missing MSVCP140D.dll error.

I would prefer to build in release mode as well but when I do that I get

```
 C1083 ipdb': Permission denied error.
```

What am I missing to be able to build this so he can run it without the dll's?

I thought I had it statically linked because after changing from MD to MT runtime library my file size increased by 1.5 MB.

Comment: You *have* to use the `Release` configuration, otherwise, your project will always try to load the debug dlls, which are only available after installation of visual studio. Maybe try to run VS in Administrator mode?

Comment: So I deleted the .suo fille and .ipdb file to be able to build the release mode version.  However now I'm still getting a missing DLL error just not the debug version of the same DLL is missing.

Comment: It is possible that you still have some runtime missing, not every runtime DLL is shipped with Windows. You can look up in which package they are and 1) ship them with your project or 2) tell the client to install the required runtime

Comment: That's not an option with this client unfortunately.  I had fixed this DLL issue earlier but I dont have that project anymore to be able to inspect the settings :(

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this was I had been using the Rest SDK installed via Nuget package manager.

I guess this wasn't being compiled in MT mode so I just removed the sdk for now.

At least until I can figure out how to compile that in MT mode.